# change style to display: block;

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails application which has some `<li>` elements with style `display: none;` CSS property. I want to make it appear on the page only while dragging that element. However, some elements **don't** have `display: none;` style. How do I do it ?

Following is my HTML code :

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                            <li id="<%=video_upload.id %>"  <% if video_upload.invisible == true %> <%= "style=display:none;" %> <%end%>   >
                                <% if mobile? %>
                                    <a href="<%= showvideo_path(video_upload.id) %>">
                                        <div style="background-color: white">
                                            <%= image_tag("/images/upload_images/"+"#{video_upload.imagename}", height: '130', width: '200') %>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                <% else %>
                                    <div style="background-color: white">
                                      <img src="<%= '/images/upload_images/'+"#{video_upload.imagename}" %>" class="img-responsive" style="cursor:pointer" onclick="popVideo('https://app.box.com/embed/s/<%= video_upload.link[/([^\/]+)$/] %>');" >
                                    </div>
                                <% end %>

                                <span style="float: left">
                                    <%= File.basename(video_upload.imagename, '.*') %>

                                </span>

                                <span style="float: right">

                                    <%= link_to '', edit_video_uploads_path(video_upload), {class: 'btn btn-primary  glyphicon glyphicon-pencil', :style => 'color: white'} %>

                                    <%= button_tag(:del_flag => 'button', :id => video_upload.id ,:class => 'btn btn-danger user-approve-btn glyphicon glyphicon-trash') do
                                    ""
                                    end %>
                                </span>
                            </li>
                        </div>
```

I am using [this](http://james2doyle.github.io/zepto-dragswap/) javascript for *drag and drop*.

Comment: Share your html code

Comment: how can you drag an element that is invisible?

Comment: hey mate, we need to see your complete html code, otherwise we won't be able to guess what you have in your page.

Comment: I don't want to drag an invisible element.. I want to make it visible while dragging other elements. That invisible element is for dropping purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select all your `<li>` elements, and show them while dragging. Then hide them when the drag ends:

```
document.querySelectorAll('li').forEach(li => {
   // Show the <li> on drag
   li.addEventListener('dragstart', event => {
       event.target.style.display = 'block';
   });

   // Hide each <li> back
   li.addEventListener('dragleave', event => {
       event.target.style.display = 'none';
   });
});
```

This is using the HTML5 native drag and drop feature as you can see in [this](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/) blog article. Let me know if it works as you want.

UPDATE:

In case that you want to select 1 element like you said, you just have to add an `id="myElement"` in that element and then select it like so:

```
let element = document.querySelector('#myElement');

element.addEventListener('dragstart', event => {
   event.target.style.display = 'block';
});
element.addEventListener('dragleave', event => {
   event.target.style.display = 'none';
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. 
I have one question. What if I only have to display and hide those elements which I want to, not all.

Comment: To be clear, I have only one element with `display: none;` property. I only have to unhide it on drag event, and hide after drop event. I am sorry for not being clear with my question.

Comment: Then select those elements with `document.querySelectorAll` and apply the same events for each one `dragstart` and `dragleave`. You could add a class to those elements like `class="example"` in your html and then select them with `document.querySelectorAll('.example')` then you would appy those events.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Merunas Grincalaitis.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145352/discussion-between-ruby-rails-and-merunas-grincalaitis).